# Can I link a decision tree to a Markov

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a cost-effectiveness analysis and the initial part of my model is a decision tree, and then a 4 state Markov model.

Using the heemod package, I get to this point,

```
mod1 <- run_model(
  mono = mod_PSA,
  comb = mod_Gene,
  cycles = 35,
  cost = cost_total,
  effect = utility,
  method = "beginning",
  init = c(X, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

however the initial values in each model need to be different based on the population values derived from the decision tree, heemod only allows me to define an equal population. Is there any way to overcome this obstacle or a different package/method I could use?

Thanks!